# I can't log into my account on Kali Linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux, password-recovery, login-screen

I've successfully installed Kali Linux, but I can't log in. My system is in Russian, and the keyboard layout is *American English*. After some Googling I had no luck. Should I reinstall it?

Comment: Please read: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am in Kali now (V2022 English). You can change the keyboard but you have to log in (you can't).

I remember the (numerous) installs and my recall is that language and keyboard were combined as one choice. Kali is not user friendly.

So then given that, yes, I suggest reinstalling either:

(a) in Russian with a Russian keyboard, or

(b) in American English with American English keyboard.

Keeping both language and keyboard the same during install will help.

Comment: But how do I boot from the DVD? It boots straight into the GRUB.

Comment: Yes my install boots straight into Grub so as I noted, not very friendly

Comment: So, it boils down to deleting partition from Windows or some sort of Live CD/USB?

Comment: You could do the live USB or as I do, Virtual Machine for Kali . That works very well . The live USB uses the host hardware and that is a plus.  You may also be able to make a bootable DVD from the Bare Metal download. I have not done that but it should work.

Comment: As far as I know, Debian (Kali) and USB aren't so "friendly" with each other. So I'll just delete that partition.

Comment: *As far as I know, Debian (Kali) and USB aren't so "friendly" with each other.* You couldn't be more wrong. Pretty much everybody uses USB sticks, not optical media, for ANY Linux or other since more than a decade ago. And Kali has a very specific target audience: Users with advanced Linux know-how doing pentesting. It's NOT intended as a desktop Linux for daily usage and definitely not for newbies. Also requires at least some hardware/fiormware (UEFI/BIOS) basic knowledge that a few of your questions show is unfortunately lacking.